# Find Possible Numerical Values of Enum Using GDB

Tags: enums, gdb

With an enum declared and instantiated like this:

```
enum test_enumeration
    {
        test1 = 4,
        test2 = 10,
        test3,
    };

test_enumeration test_enum;
```

I can call

```
(gdb) ptype test_enum
```

to get out

```
type = enum test_enumeration {test1 = 4, test2 = 10, test3}
```

This gives me the numerical value of test1 and test2 but NOT test3.
If I call

```
(gdb) print (int)test3
```

GDB prints out the value 11.
However I want to be able to get something like this:

```
type = enum test_enumeration {test1 = 4, test2 = 10, test3 = 11}
```

By printing out the entire type definition using test_enum. 
Unfortunately

```
(gdb) ptype (int)test_enum
```

returns the the type as int and not the values.

Is there a way to print out the enum constants like this or an option that needs to be set to always display their numerical versions?

GDB V10.1

Comment: You could create a new command for this with [python](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Types-In-Python.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible in GDB.  The code that decides if the `= VAL` part should be printed is here:

https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/c-typeprint.c;h=0502d31eff9605e7e2e430c8ad72908792c1b475;hb=HEAD#l1607

The value is only printed if it is not 1 more than the value of the previous enum entry.

Answer (score 4):

This will print out all the elements of an enum type. The executable needs to have been compiled with debuginfo.

```py
$ cat print-enum.py
import gdb

class PrintEnumCmd(gdb.Command):
  """print all elements of the given enum type"""

  def __init__(self):
    super(PrintEnumCmd, self).__init__("print-enum", gdb.COMMAND_DATA, gdb.COMPLETE_EXPRESSION)

  def invoke(self, argstr, from_tty):
    typename = argstr
    if not typename or typename.isspace():
      raise gdb.GdbError("Usage: print-enum type")

    try:
      t = gdb.lookup_type(typename)
    except gdb.error:
      typename = "enum " + typename
      try:
        t = gdb.lookup_type(typename)
      except gdb.error:
        raise gdb.GdbError("type " + typename + " not found")

    if t.code != gdb.TYPE_CODE_ENUM:
      raise gdb.GdbError("type " + typename + " is not an enum")

    for f in t.fields():
      print(f.name, "=", f.enumval)

PrintEnumCmd()
```

```
$ gdb enu
Reading symbols from enu...done.
(gdb) source print-enum.py
(gdb) print-enum
Usage: print-enum type
(gdb) print-enum test<tab>
test1             test2             test3             test_enumeration
(gdb) print-enum test_enumeration
test1 = 4
test2 = 10
test3 = 11
```

Comment: The Python GDB API has a make_enum_dict (enum_type) function in the gdb.types module which will do the same thing: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/gdb_002etypes.html#gdb_002etypes

Comment: @user486185 You could do `for k, v in gdb.types.make_enum_dict(t).items(): print(k, "=", v)`, but prior to CPython 3.6, dicts don’t preserve insertion order.